# I can't read a single line using getline()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, getline

I've got a class:

```
class DataBase{
private:
    fstream db_file;
public:
    DataBase(){
        db_file.open("db.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    }

    void couteverything(){
        string line;
        if(db_file.good() && db_file.is_open()){
            getline(db_file, line);
            cout << line;
            cout << "ok";
        }

    }

    ~DataBase(){
        db_file.close();
    }
};
```

and a file db.txt with some content.
I'd like to cout it to the console, but it's not working - as if the file was empty (nothing appears on the screen).

Comment: Does you'r file start with a newline character?

Comment: When you say nothing appears on the screen, does that include the "ok"? If so, then either `db_file.good()` returned false, or `db_file.open()` returned false, or you didn't call `couteverything()`.

Comment: Try an `else { cout << "not ok"; }` too while you are there

Comment: Put a std::clog << "Destruct" << std::endl in your destructor (or set a break point)

Comment: Is the file in the current directory?

Comment: Given that you never test the status of your input operations (`open`, `getline`), it's impossible to say where things go wrong.

Comment: It seems like `if(db_file.good() && db_file.is_open()){
            getline(db_file, line);` ought to be `while (getline(db_file, line)) {` if you want to read and display the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you do not test whether the file opened successfully.  Therefore, you have no idea if the file opened successfully.  Thus, your `couteverything` method can't distinguish EOF from "failed to open."  You might consider adding a check:

```
DataBase(){
    db_file.open("db.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

    if (!db_file.is_open() || !db_file.good()) {
        // put an error message here, or throw an exception.  Up to you.
    }
}
```

Once you're in `couteverything()`, presumably you want to loop over the entire file.  You need a loop for that, not an `if` statement.  Something like this:

```
    while (getline(db_file, line)) { 
        cout << line;
        cout << "ok";
    }
```

Even if you did not want to loop here (in which case `coutnextline()` might be a better name for the method), you still want to test the result of `getline()` directly, rather than testing `good()` and `is_open()` *before* each read.  You need to test whether `getline()` succeeds, otherwise your code will try to process one line beyond EOF or a read error.

```
    if (getline(db_file, line)) { 
        cout << line;
        cout << "ok";
    }
```

If you do only want to output a line at a time, I'm not sure how the code that calls this would know when to stop.  But, that's a different problem.  (Hint:  You could solve *that* by returning a `bool` from this line-at-a-time method.)